# Can I use %f and %d to format floats and ints to strings in a list?

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am a starter with python ,without any programming experience
and here's my question

I have a list called n

```
n = [ (1.1,5) , (2.4,7) , (5.4,6) , (9.8,14) , (10,4) ]
```

and I want to create a list which looks like

```
k = [ ('1.1' , {'num' : '5'}) ,
  ('2.4' , {'num' : '7'}) ,
  ('5.4' , {'num' : '6'}) ,
  ('9.8' , {'num' : '14'}) ,
  ('10' , {'num' : '4'}) 
]
```

I've tried something like

```
for  i in range(len(n)):
    k.append(('%f', {'num' : '%d'})) % n[i][0] % n[i][1]
```

but I got a `TypeError : unsupported operand type(s) for % : 'NoneType' and 'float'`

I'm not sure if I asked this question in a proper way but...hope someone can help me with this, thx T^T

Comment: For whoever added the "off-topic" close vote - this question is clear with problem, expected result and attempt and solving. Nothing close-votey about it, even if a bit basic. I've edited the title to make the OP's intent clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are already floats and ints, respectively. Your expected `k` looks like it converts them to strings. So you can build it that way with a list comprehension:

```
>>> n = [ (1.1,5) , (2.4,7) , (5.4,6) , (9.8,14) , (10,4) ]
>>> k = [ (str(x) , {'num': str(y)}) for x, y in n]
>>> k
[('1.1', {'num': '5'}), ('2.4', {'num': '7'}), ('5.4', {'num': '6'}), ('9.8', {'num': '14'}), ('10', {'num': '4'})]
>>>
```

Wrt the code you were trying:

`for  i in range(len(n)):` - this is not a good way to iterate in Python. You don't actually need the item index to reference the item in the current iteration. For example:

```
>>> for item in n:
...   print item
...
(1.1, 5)
(2.4, 7)
(5.4, 6)
(9.8, 14)
(10, 4)
>>>
>>> # let's get each part of the tuple separately:
... for item in n:
...   print 'tuple index 0:', item[0],
...   print 'tuple index 1:', item[1]
...
tuple index 0: 1.1 tuple index 1: 5
tuple index 0: 2.4 tuple index 1: 7
tuple index 0: 5.4 tuple index 1: 6
tuple index 0: 9.8 tuple index 1: 14
tuple index 0: 10 tuple index 1: 4
```

Now take a look at the part:
`k.append(('%f', {'num' : '%d'})) % n[i][0] % n[i][1]` - looks like you were trying to do the `%` substitution like in `print '%s world!' % 'hello'` => `hello world!`. For that to work, you need to use the % operator immediately after the string, like so:

```
>>> k = []
>>> for item in n:
...   k.append(('%f' % item[0], {'num': '%d' % item[1]}))
...
>>> k
[('1.100000', {'num': '5'}), ('2.400000', {'num': '7'}), ('5.400000', {'num': '6'}), ('9.800000', {'num': '14'}), ('10.000000', {'num': '4'}
)]
```

Now, instead of doing the `%` format stuff, just cast your floats and ints to strings, using `str()`. So adapting your version with these here:

```
>>> k = []
>>> for item in n:
...   k.append((str(item[0]), {'num': str(item[1])}))
...
```

And since you know `item` refers to each element in the list, and each those is always a tuple, you can expand it in the iterator-variables, like `x` and `y` used here:

```
>>> k = []
>>> for x, y in n:
...   print 'index 0:', x, '; index 1', y
...   k.append((str(x), {'num': str(y)}))
...
```

Lastly, the pattern of creating an empty list `k` and then appending items to it in a loop can be done in a more *Pythonic* way in list comprehensions:

```
>>> k = [(str(x), {'num': str(y)}) for x, y in n]
```

(Note that `k` *does not* first need to be initialised to an empty list.)

Comment: First of all THANKS for help!!!!
So the %f and %d doesn't mean that the target is float or int but are used to convert them into float and int !!
Might seems very stupid though but thank you ~~~

Comment: Thanks again for the details T^T

Comment: As a Python beginner, good attempt at solving your own problem before asking on SO. +1 for that! And welcome to SO. (added some more details so that you can do a step-by-step better-ness to the Pythonic way to having done it.)

Comment: Really appreciate that!!! I used to regard 「for i in range(len(n))」 as a counter , so I thought if I want to ask python to do an iterate job depends on the number of elements in n then I should use this to do it, even I don't really need the index lol
Learned unexpected a lot in a small question^^ Thanks again!

Comment: Correct, and that's the first thing many programmers coming from other languages do wrong in Python (actually correct, though inefficient). And the `item[n]` does an index look up for each item in the loop which is _slower_ than just `for item in n` which sets item to each item. PS: if you _do actually need a counter_ while iterating over a loop, use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).